# how to embed navigation controller in a view programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a view controller which is my HomeViewController, and I have a modal segue between them.

This is the HomeViewController:

```
import "HomePageViewController.h"
#import "CreatePageViewController.h"
#import "StackTableViewController.h"
#import "PopUpView.h"


@interface HomePageViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *toggleButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CreatePageViewController *modalTest;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PopUpView *popup;

@end

@implementation HomePageViewController

-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:Nil];
    _modalTest = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ModalTest"];

    [_toggleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(go) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(hide) name:@"HideAFPopup" object:nil];
}

-(void)go {

    _popup = [PopUpView popupWithView:_modalTest.view];
    [_popup show];
}

-(void)hide {

    [_popup hide];
}
- (IBAction)pushToNextViewController:(id)sender {

    StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}


-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

I want to add a navigation controller to StackTableViewController...its just a table view and I want it to have a navigation controller, how should I do this?

Also, why xcode tells me my modal method presentModalViewController is deprecated?

tnx

Answer (score 2):

Create a new instance of `UINavigationController`, with your `StackTableViewController` as its `rootViewController`.  Then present the navigation controller:

```
- (IBAction)pushToNextViewController:(id)sender {

    StackTableViewController *vc = [[StackTableViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    [self presentViewController:navCtrl animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

Note that `presentModalViewController:animated:` is deprecated because it has been replaced by `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.