# IOS - Objective C - " error Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a situation here, This is an image of the storyboard:

[image]

So, as you can see I have a login view controller that is connected to my tab bar controller.

What I want to do is to have a view controller instead of a tab bar controller, and this view controller will be connected to the navigation controller, something like this :

[image]

when I run my application it gives me this error :

**reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'ToMenu'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'**

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I embedded a navigation controller to Icons view controller and It still gives me the same error, this is an image of my edit in the storyboard:

### [image]

If you need more explanations/source code about my problem please let me know, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you everything:

1. Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'ToMenu'.
2. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.

1.. You have likely **not embedded your ToMenu view in a Navigation controller** and/or incorrectly named a Segue or simply not named it at all: check the name of the Segue in question.

2.. You need to embed your source view controller. This means where ever there is an expected series of Navigation, the very first one in the series needs a NavigationController.

Icons view controller is missing a navigation controller as well. Since you have segue going from it to your table view you will need a navigation controller as it's the initiating view.

---

**On a side note**, while I am sure the Storyboard looks organised and convenient to you, what a mess. It's pretty difficult to see where the issue is without seeing the whole board and with it seemingly quite scattered.

Comment: I will do what you suggested and see if it works, thanks for the side note too , I will try to make things more organized in the future , it will be more easier for me first and also for anyone who sees my storyboard

Comment: How we looking @samouray?

Comment: I embedded a navigation controller to Icons view controller and It still gives me the same error , I don't know what else should I do,  I edited my question

Comment: @samouray Where is your ToMenu segue located. Embed that view in a UINavigationController.

Comment: You also have not embedded your LoginView. You need to do that

Comment: @samouray how you looking now? Embedded your source view aka LoginView yet?

Comment: I just embedded my loginView too, the error has changed now, it gives me a different one

Comment: @samouray If the error has changed and your question has been successfully answered  please select one of the answers provided as your accepted answer. Glad I could help. Can I help with anything else?

Comment: I accepted your answer & I also fixed the other error so it's all good ^^

Comment: @samouray thanks. Glad you've got things working now.

Answer (score 1):

You have to embed your initialViewController in `UINavigationController`. Click Your initialViewController. Then Go to

> Editor--> Embed In --> Navigation Controller, to add Navigation Controller to your initial view

Comment: @samouray I have edited my answer. Please embed your initial view controller.

Comment: what do you mean by my initial viewController ? is it the one that is shown to the user when he first runs the app  ?

Comment: @samouray. Yes you can say that. Basically in your storyboard it is the first controller that loads.

Comment: I actually change the initial view controller programmatically :  if the user is authenticated the icons view controller will be the initial view controller or else the login view controller will be the initial view controller, so what should I do in this case ?

Comment: @samouray check this ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27094184/how-to-embed-navigation-controller-in-a-view-programmatically